# Sum of independent binomially distributed variables (with different p's)?

Tags: binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

The sum of independent variables each following binomial distributions $B(N_i,p_i)$ is also binomial if all $p_i = p$ are equal (in this case the sum follows $B(\sum_i N_i, p)$. If the $p_i$ are distinct, the sum follows the more general [Poisson-Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution).

The Poisson-Binomial with parameters $q_k$ is the distribution of the sum of Bernoulli variables with success probabilities $q_k$. Since a binomial $B(N_i,p_i)$ is the sum of $N_i$ Bernoulli variables with success probability $p_i$, it follows that the sum of binomials considered above is equal to the Poisson-Binomial, with parameters $p_1,p_1,\dots$ (repeated $N_1$ times), $p_2,p_2,\dots$ (repeated $N_2$ times),  ..., being the sum of $\sum_i N_i$ Bernoulli variables.

Instead of describing the distribution with a list $p_1,p_1,\dots$ (repeated $N_1$ times), $p_2,p_2,\dots$ (repeated $N_2$ times),  ..., where each success probability $p_i$ appears repeated $N_i$ times, one can also describe this distribution with the parameter pairs $(N_1,p_1), (N_2,p_2),\dots$. Is there a name for the Poisson-Binomial distribution when described in this form?

Comment: "The sum of independent non-identically distributed binomial random variables."  But this sum also follows the Poisson-Binomial distribution.  Is there really a need for another term?

Comment: @JimB As I say in the question, I know that the sum of binomial variables follows a Poisson-Binomial distribution. But the Poisson-Binomial is a bit more general, because it doesn't care that there are success rates repeated $N_i$ times. I am just asking if another term exists in the literature that applies specifically to this case. I am not demanding that it is necessary.

Comment: Sorry.  You were very clear in your question and I wasn't very clear in my comment.  I was simply curious if there was some other motivating factor.  It has been my observation over 40 years of being a statistician that statisticians tend not to want to make new names for specific departures of standard procedures and that when a new name is introduced it is many times from someone in a different field.  (Note that I have no hard evidence for this.  John Tukey was an exception.)

Comment: It would just be an alternative parameterization for the poisson-binomial.